# how to apply function to every element in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda, map-function

I want to apply resolve_on to every element in list c1, like

```
for(Char c:c1){
resolve_on c c1 c2;}
```

So how can I do this using map function?

```
resolvents :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
resolvents c1 c2 =  map (//what should I do) c1

resolve_on :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
resolve_on c c1 c2
```

Comment: Note that function in Haskell are pure, so just "apply" the function on a list would do nothing. I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: Did you know about lambda function in Haskell?

Comment: Haskell is a functional language so there is not much *doing* things, it is more *defining* things. If the function is a monad (for example a state or `IO` monad), then `mapM` is probably the closest to that.

Comment: Im trying to use resolve_on function on every element in c1, so like c1 = ["a","b","c"] I want to do resolve_on "a" c1 c2, resolve_on "b" c1 c2 and resolve_on "c" c1 c2 by using map function. (map resolve_on c1? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, start with list comprehensions:

```
-- for (Char c) in c1:                     do { c <- c1
--   yield (resolve_on c c1 c2)               ; return (resolve_on c c1 c2) }

resolvents c1 c2 = [ resolve_on c c1 c2 | c <- c1 ]

    -- read it:    a list of
    --              (resolve_on c c1 c2)
    --                                  for        -- or: for every
    --                                    c
    --                                      in c1
```

This is indeed a `map`,

```
                 = map (\c -> resolve_on c c1 c2) c1
```

This uses a *lambda* (i.e., unnamed) *function*, receiving one argument named `c`.

The `do` code in the comments would also work. It is in `do` notation, and is equivalent to the list comprehension.

Comment: Hi I want to ask what does this "|" notation mean here, does it signal the start of the for loop (c<-c1)?

Comment: see https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7C. I've also edited the answer.

Comment: you're welcome. :) I believe it is easier to grasp new things when seeing several ways of doing the same thing, at once, including pseudocode.

Comment: Hi, one more question, is it possible to add a condition directly inside , like  [ if c `elem` c2 then resolve_on c c1 c2 | c <- c1 ]?

Comment: yes (you should really look up "list comprehension" to get the full picture, but you could also browse the page I linked, e.g. [see this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.2C)): ``[ resolve_on c c1 c2 | c <- c1, elem c c2 ]``. Any Boolean value serves as a filter: the element `c` is skipped if the expression has the value `False`.